# Convert MODIS LST in HDF to Geotiff using Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-conversion, geotiff, hdf, format-conversion

I have downloaded land surface temperature grids from MODIS, which are in .hdf format. 
I would like to convert the folder containing these .hdfs into geotiffs for easier processing.

I have attempted using the `hdfread('/User/....hdf')` command, but if I only give my hdf file as an input, it has not enough input parameters. The help function specifies that here I should input my datasetname.

```
hdfinfo = 
  Filename: '/Users/Desktop//MODIS_MAT_2000_2014/2005/MOD11C3.A2005001.004.2005035221349.hdf'
  Attributes: [1x4 struct]
  Vgroup: [1x1 struct]

hdfinfo.Vgroup.Name
ans = MODIS_MONTHLY_0.05DEG_CMG_LST
```

But if I input this as my datasetname, I get an error. Does anybody have any experience with loading hdf files this way?

Code:

```
fileinfo = hdfread('/Users/Desktop/Windows_data/MODIS_MAT_2000_2014/2005/MOD11C3.A2005001.004.2005035221349.hdf');
```

Error message: 'Not enough input arguments' since I miss this datasetname, but I don't know how to find what the different datasets are named. There is also no SDS that I can access, only Attributes and Vgroup.

Comment: Please show us the code which you using to read the dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! My code looks as follows:

fileinfo = hdfread('/Users/Desktop/Windows_data/MODIS_MAT_2000_2014/2005/MOD11C3.A2005001.004.2005035221349.hdf');

atr_info = fileinfo.Attributes

The problem is, that I would like to acces SDS datasets,. I only have this the Vgroup and the Attributes, which consist of 4 subdatasets. I know the hdf files consist of 16 subdatasets, but I cannot seem to acces them. 

source: 
https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod11c1

But the files convert easily in ArcGIS for example.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`hdfread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdfread.html#examples) gives a few examples for how to use the function.

One way is to use the dataset name as you tried to do, but another is to [use the hdfinfo directly](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdfread.html#f12-479666).

You can try

```
fileinfo = hdfinfo(''/User/....hdf') %Get the info
sds_info = fileinfo.SDS(2) %Choose a dataset
data = hdfread(sds_info); %Read the dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the solution myself, by adjusting my code as follows:

```
hdfread(fullfile('/Users/Desktop/Windows_data/MODIS_MAT_2000_2014/2006','LST_Day_CMG');
```

I just could not find the right header (which was 'LST_Day_CMG' in this case), which I in the end found on the MODIS website.